# Ubuntu 14.10 Lightdm greeter resolution before login

Tags: login, resolution, lightdm, login-screen

There are various answers for changing the resolution of the Lightdm greeter before login by adding a root executable script to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/somewhere/myscript.sh
session-setup-script=/somewhere/myscript.sh
```

Where myscript.sh contains a xrandr command.

This is not quite working for me in Ubuntu 14.10.

On booting, as the Lightdm greeter appears for the first time the resolution is what I want.

But a second later it switches back to the default resolution which I don't want.

I guess there is some Ubuntu config that is occurring after myscript runs.

Anyone know the config sequence, or where later I could execute the myscript.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I added a script to use "xrandr" so it will setup the screen/resolution on lightdm, but after being all setup, if you wait for about 2 seconds or so, it will revert back to some other setting. So, looks like my script with "xrandr" runs then something else runs.